# Problema con Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en Web asp.NET web api (WebService) el cual utiliza una seguridad de autenticacion basica. Por otro lado tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C# la cual llama a los metodos (WebService) para realizar unos procesos.
El problema es que aunque la aplicación funciona correctamente, he detectado que en algunos momentos va un poco lenta y analizando el log ubicado en `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2` me he encontrado esto:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-02-12 09:30:48
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-02-12 09:30:45 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 1216
2018-02-12 09:30:45 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 308
2018-02-12 09:30:45 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 57
2018-02-12 09:30:45 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 6
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 47
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 48
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 52
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 17
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 1
2018-02-12 09:31:39 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 401 2 5 6
2018-02-12 09:31:38 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 80
2018-02-12 09:31:39 W3SVC2 WS2016 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST /ServiceMain.asmx wsdl 8090 DOMAIN\USER XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.8825) - - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090 200 0 0 58
```

Veo que se estan rechazando peticiones (401 2 5) pero luego las acepta (200 0 0)...

El usuario del dominio lo he metido en el grupo de administradores para probar si fuera este el problema y sigue fallando.

He probado multitud de cosas que he ido leyendo por el foro, pero no encuentro la solucion.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Al menos desde navegadores, el comportamiento estándar es hacer la petición sin autenticación y, cuando llega el 401, entonces solicitar la información al usuario y enviarla. ¿Puede ser que el log se refiera a petición desde el navegador? En ese caso el comportamiento sería el esperado.

Comment: Es posible, pero he hecho pruebas desde Chrome y no me da esos errores, todos las peticiones me contesta con 200 (Ok).

Comment: No significa que primero las rechace y luego las acepte, un registro es una petición y básicamente lo que está pasando es que la autenticación va mal en la llamada al API. El error 401 se refiere a: "*Similar al error 403 Prohibido, pero específicamente la autenticación es requerida y ha fallado o no ha sido provista*"